# Surjectivity of Scalar Extension map between Hom-Spaces of projective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $R\to R'$ be a morphism of commutative rings and $M$, $N$ two finitely generated projective $R$-modules. Is it true that the map
\begin{align*}
\text{Hom}_R(M,N) \otimes R'&\to \text{Hom}_{R'}(M\otimes R',N\otimes R')\\
(f\otimes r'&\mapsto ((m\otimes s')\mapsto (r'f(m)\otimes s'))
\end{align*}
is surjective?

This is true if $R\to R'$ is a localization, see e.g. [Show that this mapping between localized modules is an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215221/show-that-this-mapping-between-localized-modules-is-an-isomorphism). This, however, uses exactness of localization, and $-\otimes R'$ is only right exact.